# Unhandled exception occurs when Clicking Save Button

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

```cs
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidInput())
        return;
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        command = new OleDbCommand("insert into Students (RollNo, SName, FName, DOB, Class, Section) values (@RollNo, @SName, @FName, @DOB, @Class, @Section)", conn);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("RollNo", txtRollNo.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("SName", txtSName.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("FName", txtFName.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("DOB", dtpDOB.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Class", cmbClass.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Section", cmbSection.Text));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    }
}
```

When I Click Save Button this error is rising (**Insert Into Syntax Error**).

[image: error]

I have troubleshooted the code, I Find that if Field **Section** and Parameter **@Section** is removed from **insert** statement. Then Code works fine. But I want to Get ComboBox(**CmbSection**) Value of it and also to store on Database. How Can I?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Is `section` a MS Access reserved word? Try `[Section]`.

Comment: I have attached error image. It gives (Insert Into statement syntax Error). When clicking the Save Button.

Comment: Didn't know that "Section" is reserved word in MS-Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Section" is [a reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words) in MS Access, so its use here is confusing the query parser.

You can explicitly tell the query what identifiers are referring to database objects (columns, tables, etc.) by wrapping them in square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO [Students]
    ([RollNo], [SName], [FName], [DOB], [Class], [Section])
    VALUES (@RollNo, @SName, @FName, @DOB, @Class, @Section)
```